# How to count likes on FB page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have to do a very simple operation but my programming skills are not enough. I have to count likes in Facebook page and print that number on my web-site. I have two scripts that do the job well for ordinary web-sites, but they don't want to show the number of likes for the page.

```
<?php
$source_url = "http://www.facebook.com/";  //This could be anything URL source  including stripslashes($_POST['url'])
$url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
$likes =  $xml->link_stat->like_count;
$comments = $xml->link_stat->comment_count;
$total = $xml->link_stat->total_count;
$max = max($shares,$likes,$comments);
echo $likes;
?>

<?php
$fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
$fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
$fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = 'http://www.apple.com/'";
$apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
$json=file_get_contents($apifql);
print_r( json_decode($json));
?>
```

Both scripts work for ordinary web-sites but cant fetch fb page likes number. May be I should enter the link in another format or something?

I can get required data using graph like this http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=AutoSpecCenter , just by entering page name like that. But I don't know how to manipulate with this data.

Comment: So you don't know how to parse the response from graph.facebook.com?

Comment: Actually yes :/. I know this might be trivial, so im a bit ashamed of my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already wrote in your question, you can query such information through Facebooks' Graph API. This short example will get the information of the Coca-Cola page, decode the JSON and outputs the number of people that like the page `$data->likes`.

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/CocaCola?access_token=<Access Token>");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($raw);
echo $data->likes . " people like Coca-Cola";
?>
```

If you need to perform more tasks than just getting the likes of a page, consider using the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) as *cpilko* suggested.

Comment: Hello, this is not working, query returns an error with message ```An access token is required to request this resource.```

Comment: Because since my answer in 2012 and now, Facebook changed the API and it now requires an access_token, add an access token and it should work again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the quick and dirty way:

```
<?php
$fb_id = 'AutoSpecCenter';
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . urlencode($fb_id);
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
printf("<p>There are %s people who like %s</p>", $result->likes, $result->name);
```

You'd do much better off installing the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) or using cURL to get this.

You could set `$fb_id` equal to a url as well.

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not work with the Graph API ;-) You have to use cURL or something else.

Answer (score 1):

here is a easy way too....

`<?php
    $page_id = 'yourfbpageid';  // your facebook page id
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
    $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
?>
<li class="text white"><span></span><?php echo $fans.' Fans'; ?></li>`

courtesy:ravi patel

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
<?php
function getData($username){

$access_token = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN'; //Replace it with your Access Token
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/".$username."?fields=fan_count&access_token=".$access_token),true);
return $json;
}

$data = getData("Mypage");//Replace it with your Username


$likes = $data['fan_count'];
echo "Facebook Likes: ".$likes;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem, just adding `likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)` in parameter in against "fields" worked for me.

e.g. I used `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=story,from,story_tags,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)`

instead of `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Also you can add other parameters if you want; separated by a ,

Also if you want count of single post you can use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=true&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

for likes count

Or

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/comments?summary=true&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

for comment count

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php echo facebooklike('209414452444193');

      function facebooklike($page_id){

       $likes = 0; //Initialize the count  
       //Construct a Facebook URL
       $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'';
       $json = get_contents($json_url);
       $json_output = json_decode($json);

      //Extract the likes count from the JSON object
      if($json_output->likes){
        $likes = $json_output->likes;
      }
      return $likes;   
    }
    function get_contents($url){
       $ch = curl_init($url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       $data = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       return $data;
    }
?>
```