# I want to customize the facebook buttons like "2201 Fans" into my website

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I want to cutomize the facebook buttons like "2201 Fans" into my website .. but in facebook developer site its like auto generated button .... I'm now working on a wordpress site ....  plugin will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

> Display no of fans on your site using  facebook page id.

```
<?php
    $page_id = 'yourfbpageid';  // your facebook page id
    $xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
    $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
?>
<li class="text white"><span></span><?php echo $fans.' Fans'; ?></li>
```

Comment: thanks for the code ... but i dont have facebook page ... i want to show fans who like my website....

Comment: use this code -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147642/how-to-count-likes-on-fb-page